# Loading PDF in an iframe with out the html page behind the iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, angular8, jspdf

[stackblitz code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-final?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html)

i am working on a angular application to export PDF .

my app structure: i have 2 components (login,home) ,created a button(export) in login component and which will navigate the user to home component and afterViewInit it will generate the pdf based on home component html. everything is working fine except i see the html in the background along with the PDF form.
my solution : we can make the pdf full frame(100%) but i need a button to go back to previous page.

questions :

1. how can we make html invisble behind the screen
2. is there any way we can implement this with out 2 components and routing (ex: hidden html in same login component) ?

Comment: Why dont you open the PDF in a popup window?

Comment: that is our design, @Chin.Udara

Comment: @Chin.Udara if we don't have any other options then i will ask my PO to consider pop up

Comment: Okay, you could just add a `style="display: none"` to `tablepdf` div. The PDF will still be generated with the `innerHTML` of the element.

Comment: @Chin.Udara with disply none , we need to show the button below the iframe to go back to the previous page. but it is not showing up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an answer because this is too much to be written as a comment.

As I suggested in the comment; you can `display: none` the `tablepdf` div.

You have your iFrame below that div. So it wont affect any of the content you have outside of the `tablepdf`.

You are not seeing the back button after setting display to none because the back button is behind your iFrame. iFrame is set to `position:fixed`

To show the back button, you could make the following changes.

```
<!-- set the parent div height to 100vh so that the 90% height in the iFrame can work properly -->
<div class="row" style="height: 100vh">
   <!-- remove the position: fixed so that your button can be shown below the iFrame -->
   <iframe id="main-iframe" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; z-index: 2; border: none;"></iframe>
   <button class="btn btn-primary " (click)="goback()">go back</button>
</div>
```